# A two-digit number is $10$ times more than the sum of its digits. The units digit is 1 more than twice the tens digit. Find the two-digit number.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

**Background**

This problem is an entry-level one on the competition problems page of AoPS. ([Source.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AoPS_Wiki:Competition_ratings#Introductory_Competitions))

The link it provides to a solution does not contain a solution to the problem, but rather to some other problems.

**Problem statement**

> The value of a two-digit number is $10$ times more than the sum of its digits. The units digit is 1 more than twice the tens digit. Find the two-digit number.

**Thoughts**

The problem is stated in a way that alludes to the idea that a solution should exist, but I can't find one.

The first constraint is that the value of the number should be $10$ times larger than its digit sum is easily solved.

Let $x$ and $y$ be the digits of the number, and let the notation be $[xy] = 10x + y$. We see immediately that $y=0$ provides nine solutions, $10, 20, \ldots, 90$.

The second constraint suggests that $y=2x+1$. For this to be true, we must constrain $x \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $y\in \{3, 5, 7, 9\}$. We then have only four candidates, $13, 25, 37, 49$, none of which satisfy the first constraint.

Conclusion: No solution.

**Question**

The only reason I'm doubting my solution is because of the wording of the problem. Am I being given the run-around here?

Comment: If it is $10$ times the sum of its digits then $10, 20, 30$ etc. are solutions but if it is $10$ times _more_, then $11 (a + b) = 10 a + b$ and hence I do not see any solutions as you said.

Comment: @MathLover - Hold up, do we not consider 10 to be 10 times *more* than 1?

Comment: "is 10 times more than"  It is not at all clear what this means?  "is 10 times" means $10x + y = 10(x + y)$ and "is 10 more than" means $10x + y = 10 + (x+y)$.  But "is 10 times more than" is ambiguous at best and meaningless at worse.

Comment: "Hold up, do we not consider 10 to be 10 times more than 1?"  I most certainly do *not*!  I consider $10$ to be $10$ times $1$ and I consider $10$ to be $9$ more than $1$ but I consider "$10$ times more than $1$" to be an utterly confusing statement I can't make heads or tails out of.  At *best* I'd consider it to bo $10 = 10\times 1 + 1 = 11$ as Math Lover did but I'd sooner say the author is not at all being clear.

Comment: Plainly, a number $[x,2x+1]$ has a digit sum $3x+1$ and a value $12x+1$. What it means to say that one of these is $10$ times "more than" the other is beyond me. They cannot have a ratio of $10$, and their difference $9x$ cannot be a multiple of either $10$ or $11$ for single digit $x$.

Comment: Okay, I think the question has an english error and a typo.  I think it means to se the number is $10$ times the sum of the digits (not "ten times *more* than" which does not make any sense).  And I think the got the second part backwards and meant to so the *tens* digit is $1$ more than twice the *unit* digit.  In other words.... the number is $10$.  However as it is written.... it's just a mess.

Comment: "*do we not consider 10 to be 10 times more than 1?*" I consider 10 to be nine times bigger than 1.